# Build RPM subpackages without a base package

Tags: packaging, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

According to a RPM documentation/guide (http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-subpack.html) one can use subpackages to build multiple RPM packages with a single SPEC file. In the mentioned link the packages foo, foo-server, foo-client and bazlib are built and packaged.

In the example, the SPEC file has a base/parent package called foo (server, client and bazlib are subpackages):

```bsh
Name: foo
Version: 2.7
Release: 1
Source: foo-2.7.tgz
License: probably not
Summary: The foo app, and the baz library needed to build it
Group: bogus/junque
%description
This is the long description of the foo app, and the baz library needed to
build it...

%package server
Summary: The foo server
Group: bogus/junque
%description server
This is the long description for the foo server...

%package client
Summary: The foo client
Group: bogus/junque
%description client
This is the long description for the foo client...

%package -n bazlib
Version: 5.6
Summary: The baz library
Group: bogus/junque
%description -n bazlib
This is the long description for the bazlib...

...snipped
```

Building these packages results in these packages:

```bsh
# rpmbuild -ba foo-2.7.spec
* Package: foo
* Package: foo-server
* Package: foo-client
* Package: bazlib

...snipped
```

Several questions:

1.) Has the base/parent package foo some special purpose, e.g. some additional flags/attributes in the RPIO? Or is the package foo from an RPM-"point of view" equal to all it's subpackages? If so, why are these packages then called subpackages (The word **sub**packages implies a special relationship)?

2.) Let's say I package a product with several binaries (toola, toolb, toolc) via subpackages, is there a way to disable the base/parent package? In my case, there is no need for a special base/parent package because all tool-packages are treated equally (This question is related to question 1).

I guess there is the possibility to just build tool (base/parent package) and toola, toolb, toolc, but not add tool to the repository. But this somehow feels wrong (Maybe one can use toola as base package and toolb and toolc as subpackages?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as the binary RPMs are concerned, the main package and its subpackages are equal. I can think of a couple of reasons subpackages are called that: they are described as “variants” of the main package, inheriting many fields from it (although they can be overridden), and even taking their name from it by default; and from a source package perspective, they are subpackages of the overall source package, which has the same name as the main package.
2. If the main package isn’t needed, ensure that its `%files` list is empty, and it won’t be generated. See [the “Controlling Packages With the %files List” section](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-subpack-spec-file-changes.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense. I had an old RPM file laying in the rpmbuild directory, so I thought only subpackages with an empty %files section result in no RPM (But of course it was from an old build/SPEC file)